# Spring MVC URL pattern mapping in web.xml?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have below config in web.xml

```
<servlet>  
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>  
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:spring/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
         </init-param>  
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>  
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>  
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>  
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>  
    </servlet-mapping>
```

I have controller as below.

```
@Controller  
public class SomeController { 

   @RequestMapping("/somePath")
    public String showExtendedUi() {
        return "somePage";
    }


}
```

Now client would call the controller by sending url params as belo:

```
http://localhost:8080/myApp/somePath?param1=456&param2=456
```

But the controller method is not being called.

Is my URL correct?

Answer (score 6):

Your controller method is not being invoked because you have mapped `mvc-dispatcher` to `*.do`
Change servlet mapping to

```
<servlet-mapping>  
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>  
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>  
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Or change the annotation and url to @RequestMapping("/somePath.do") of course. In any case the configuration needs to made so the rules don't conflict with each other.

Comment: If config `/`, then will static resource like image / js / css also been get by springMVC dispatcher ?

Answer (score 2):

As the URL pattern for Dispatcher Servlet is configured as *.do, The controller would be called only only by url requests of pattern "something.do".

so your url `http://localhost:8080/myApp/somePath.do?param1=456&param2=456` would work if all other configurations are made properly.