# How spring use https for request automatically?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-security

I'm implementing a web application using spring 3.2.8.RELEASE and tomcat 7.0.55.

I need spring to use https for some requests for example '/login' but not for all requests.

The application runs on http and https perfectly, but I want to filter some request to run on https automatically.

How can I config spring to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure that https is required by adding [requires-channel- attribute](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/#nsa-intercept-url-requires-channel) on each intercept-url.

**For example:**

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/your_url" access="your_role" requires-channel="https"/>
```

**EDIT:**

Required spring security mappings in web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

I hope this will work.

Comment: Thanks, and which config should I add to web.xml?? Is it necessary to define securityChainFIlter in web.xml?

Comment: Yes Its necessary. I am updating my answer.

Comment: If it solved your problem, please accept and up vote this answer so that it can help others also.

Comment: Thanks @Babak Behzadi, 1 upvote to you from my side :)

Answer (score 1):

If your application supports both HTTP and HTTPS, and you require that particular URLs can only be accessed over HTTPS, then this is directly supported using the requires-channel attribute on :

```
  <http>
    <intercept-url pattern="/secure/**" access="ROLE_USER" requires-channel="https"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" requires-channel="any"/>
    ...
  </http>
```

Comment: Thanks, and which config should I add to web.xml?? Is it necessary to define securityChainFIlter in web.xml?

Comment: please see: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/ns-config.html#ns-requires-channel

Comment: Thanks for your attention!

Answer (score 0):

Spring uses a controller servlet for all its internal URL mapping. To avoid using this controller, change the URL mapping in your Web.xml file.

Look here for a similar answer: [Spring MVC URL pattern mappping in web.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22610669/spring-mvc-url-pattern-mappping-in-web-xml)

OR look here for the spring documentation on configuring the 'front controller': http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html. This will also give you a good overview of how this works and fits together.

Good luck, and let me know if you need more help!!

BTW: I thought I would throw this in for good measure. Here  you can see the mapping goes to `/example/...`. You can also set this sort of stuff in the spring config file, but it all follows the same principle.

```
<web-app>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>example</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>example</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/example/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```